# inverse image under the inclusion and extension by zero

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ consists of two points and has discrete topology, namely  $X=\{p_1\} \coprod \{p_2\}$. Let $\iota_i: \{p_i\} \to X$ be the inclusion map. Let $\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \in \mathcal{Sh}(X)$ be the constant sheaf. What is $\iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ the inverse image of $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$.

First at the stalk level we have $\iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{p_1} \cong \underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{p_1} = \mathbb{Z}$, which implies the global $\Gamma(p_1, \iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}})= \mathbb{Z}$. Or we can  compute by definition the colimit of
$\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{(1,0)}\mathbb{Z}$ which also gives $\Gamma(p_1, \iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}})= \mathbb{Z}$.

However if we consider the short exact sequence of sheaves
$$0\to j_!\iota_2^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to \iota_1^\ast\iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}} \to 0 $$
where $ j_!\iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ is  extension by zero,  i.e the sheaf with $ j_!\iota_2^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U) = \iota_2^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U)$ if $U \subset p_1$, and $0$ otherwise.
Then if we take the global section, since $\Gamma(X, \iota_1^\ast\iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}})= \Gamma(p_1, \iota_1^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}) = \mathbb{Z}$, we get
$0\to0\to\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ which is not exact.

I cannot see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said that $j_!\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(V)=0$ if $V\not\subset\{p_1\}$. But this is wrong. More generally, if $j:U\to X$ is the inclusion of an open subset, then the property $j_!\mathcal{F}(V)=0$ if $V\not\subset U$ does not hold in general.

In fact the association $V\mapsto \begin{cases}\mathcal{F}(U)&\text{if $V\subset U$}\\ 0&\text{if $V\not\subset U$}\end{cases}$ only define a presheaf and $j_!\mathcal{F}$ is the *sheaf associated* to it.

The two points set is a striking example. You get many others when you realize that $\mathcal{F}(U_1\sqcup U_2)=\mathcal{F}(U_1)\times\mathcal{F}(U_2)$, so if $U_1$ is a subset of $U$ and $U_2$ is not, $U_1\cup U_2\not\subset U$ but $\mathcal{F}(U_1\sqcup U_2)\neq 0$ in general. You can even have connected $V\not\subset U$ with the property that $j_!\mathcal{F}(V)\neq 0$.

---

As for the pullback of a constant sheaf, there is an easy answer : it is always the constant sheaf with the same stalks. In fact if $E$ is any set then the constant sheaf $\underline{E}$ on $X$ is the pullback $a_X^{-1}E$ where $a_X:X\to\{*\}$. It follows that for any map $f:Y\to X, f^{-1}\underline{E}=f^{-1}a_X^{-1}E=(a_Xf)^{-1}E=a_Y^{-1}E=\underline{E}$.